# Class-Path line too long

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, classpath, wildfly, java-client

I developed `application client` by Java and it was running normally by `Glassfish` ..

But after moving to `Wildfly` .. i'm facing this error :

`Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYSRV0161: Failed to get manifest for deployment \"/content/Application.jar\"
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: line too long"}}`

I expect the error is because of the long line of `Class-Path` in `Manifest.mf` file.

```
Class-Path: ../lib/jaybird-2.1.6.jar ../lib/rtfparserkit-1.6.0.jar ../lib/jug-lgpl-2.0.0.jar ../lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.37-bin.jar ../lib/trilead-ssh2-build213.jar ../lib/wsdl4j-1.6.2.jar ../lib/wsdl4j-qname-1.6.1.jar ../lib/xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar ../lib/poi-3.11-20141221.jar ../lib/poi-ooxml-3.11-20141221.jar ../lib/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.11-20141221.jar ../lib/jersey-apache-client-1.16.jar ../lib/jersey-bundle-1.16.jar ../lib/jersey-core-1.16.jar ../lib/jersey-client-1.16.jar ../lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar ../lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.2.jar ../lib/js-14.jar ../lib/drools-core-5.0.1.jar ../lib/activemq-all-5.10.0.jar ../lib/json-simple-1.1.1.jar ../lib/commons-io-2.4.jar ../lib/javassist.jar ../lib/scannotation-1.0.2.jar ../lib/j-text-utils-0.3.3.jar ../lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar ../lib/commons-net-3.3.jar ../lib/opencsv-2.4.jar ../lib/gson-2.2.4.jar ../lib/httpclient-4.3.5.jar ../lib/commons-vfs-20100924-pentaho.jar ../lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar ../lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar ../lib/spring-core-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar ../lib/commons-digester-2.1.jar ../lib/commons-beanutils-1.9.2.jar ../lib/ognl-2.7.3.jar ../lib/jxl-2.6.3.jar ../lib/metastore-5.0.1.jar ../lib/edtftpj-2.1.0.jar ../lib/kettle5-log4j-plugin-5.1.0.0-752.jar ../lib/kettle-db-4.4.0-stable.jar ../lib/janino-2.5.16.jar ../lib/commons-compiler-2.7.8.jar
```

Is there any way else to load all jars inside a folder without typing this long line ? or How to avoid this error message ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting multiple jars in java classpath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/219585/setting-multiple-jars-in-java-classpath)

Comment: Did you wrap the line correctly?

Comment: @Tom this is not a duplicate of the link you provided. It's a line wrapping problem in the Manifest.mf `Class-Path` entry.

Comment: @SteveC You're right, since OP didn't ask *"Is there any way else to load all jars inside a folder without typing this long line ?"* ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The manifest-file must not contain lines longer than 72 bytes.

You have to break the line after exact 72 bytes.

```
Class-Path: ../lib/jaybird-2.1.6.jar ../lib/rtfparserkit-1.6.0.jar ../l
 ib/jug-lgpl-2.0.0.jar ../lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.37-bin.jar ../li
 b/trilead-ssh2-build213.jar ../lib/wsdl4j-1.6.2.jar ../lib/wsdl4j-qnam
 e-1.6.1.jar ...
```

Look for **Line length** in the specification:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#JAR_Manifest

**Alternative:** Do not use the classpath in Manifest. Instead start with commandline argument:

```
java -cp lib/* mainclass
```

Comment: The usual strategy is to have your build tool generate this entry for you. I know that Maven can do this.

Comment: How can i use `java -cp` with `appclient.sh` for `wildfly` ?

Comment: @Jason4Ever Sorry, I don´t know _appclient.sh for wildfly_. Is this file generated? As @Steve C posted, normally we don´t write this by hand, but it get´s generated. My alternative `java -cp lib/*' is for the console (cmd, bash, terminal etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Make an [uber jar](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html) containing  all the others.

Comment: Kindly write a sample for `pom.xml` file ? .. i tried but isn't working successfully .

Comment: `<build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    
                    <configuration>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>/home/project/lib/</directory>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>`

Answer (score 0):

FWIW:  After some time looking for a solution to this problem, and I finally found something that works.  I tested it successfully on both `Windows 10` with `java 1.8.0_241` and on `Linux Mint 19.1` with java `1.8.0_241`

Notice that each classpath entry after the `"Class-path:"` line is indented 2 spaces, although that might not be required.  Here's my `MANIFEST.MF` file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Scala-Compiler-Version: 2.12.10
Main-Class: Main
Class-Path: /opt/uejlib2.12/vastblue_2.12.jar
  /opt/uejlib2.12/apps_2.12.jar
  /opt/uejlib2.12/scala-reflect.jar
  /opt/uejlib2.12/scala-library.jar
  /opt/uejlib2.12/better-files_2.12-3.8.0.jar
  /opt/uejlib2.12/scala-collection-compat_2.12-2.1.3.jar
  /opt/uejlib2.12/chronoscala_2.12-0.3.2.jar
  /opt/uejlib2.12/sfm-csv-8.2.1.jar
  /opt/uejlib2.12/sfm-map-8.2.1.jar
  /opt/uejlib2.12/lightning-csv-8.2.1.jar
  /opt/uejlib2.12/sfm-tuples-8.2.1.jar
  /opt/uejlib2.12/sfm-reflect-8.2.1.jar
  /opt/uejlib2.12/sfm-converter-8.2.1.jar
  /opt/uejlib2.12/sfm-util-8.2.1.jar
```